# JavaScript ¿Cómo puedo hacer que apareza la variable más alta y más baja?

Tags: javascript

Qué tal? Tengo un exámen dentro de unos días y estoy haciendo un modelo para prácticar, este es uno de los ejercicios que me dieron del cúal solo pude hacer la mitad: *La jefa de una fábrica tiene que contar la cantidad de productos defectuosos por cada máquina en funcionamiento. La fábrica tiene 14 máquinas en funcionamiento. Hacer el programa que le permita a la jefa ingresar los datos de la cantidad de productos defectuosos por cada máquina. Luego calcular la cantidad de productos defectuosos totales considerando todas las máquinas y el promedio de productos defectuosos por máquina. También calcular la cantidad de productos defectuosos de la máquina que menos productos defectuosos tiene y la cantidad de productos defectuosos de la máquina que más productos defectuosos tiene. Por último calcular cuántos serían los productos defectuosos si todas las máquinas tuvieran la misma cantidad de productos defectuosos que la máquina que menos tiene. Verificar que todos los datos ingresados sean válidos (números iguales o mayores a 0) y mostrar los resultados en la página.*

Hice todo tranquilamente hasta la parte de hacer el promedio, pero cuando pide que calcular cuántos serían los productos defectuosos si todas las maquinas tuvieran la misma cantidad que la maquina que menos tiene, no se me ocurrió como seguir. Si alguien sabe como se puede seguir y explicarme, me ayudaría muchisimo, gracias! Acá les dejo el código que llegué a hacer hasta ahora, en mis clases por ahora nos van enseñando lo básico:

```
<script>
            var maquinastotales;
            var defectuoso1, defectuoso2, defectuoso3, defectuoso4, defectuoso5,defectuoso6, defectuoso7, defectuoso8, defectuoso9, defectuoso10, defectuoso11, defectuoso12, defectuoso13, defectuoso14;

            defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso2 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso3 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso4 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso5 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso6 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso7 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso8 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso9 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso10 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso11 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso12 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso13 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
            defectuoso14 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));

            while(isNaN(defectuoso1, defectuoso2, defectuoso3, defectuoso4, defectuoso5,defectuoso6, defectuoso7, defectuoso8, defectuoso9, defectuoso10, defectuoso11, defectuoso12, defectuoso13, defectuoso14))
            {
                defectuoso1 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso2 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso3 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso4 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso5 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso6 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso7 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso8 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso9 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso10 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso11 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso12 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso13 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));
                defectuoso14 = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad válida de productos defectuosos', ''));


            }
                
            var cant_defectuoso_total;
            var promedio_productos;
            var defectuoso_menor;
            var defectuoso_mayor;

            cant_defectuoso_total = (defectuoso1+defectuoso2+defectuoso3+defectuoso4+defectuoso5+defectuoso6+defectuoso7+defectuoso8+defectuoso9+defectuoso10+defectuoso11+defectuoso12+ defectuoso13+defectuoso14);
            promedio_productos = cant_defectuoso_total / 14;


            document.write('Cantidad de productos defectuosos totales: '+cant_defectuoso_total+'<br>');
            document.write('Promedio de productos defectuosos por máquina: '+promedio_productos+'<br>');



        </script>
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Edita, por favor, tu pregunta y añade el código con lo que has intentado y el error o consulta que tienes. De esta forma podremos ayudarte sino podría parecer que se solicita hacer una "tarea" y la comunidad la puntuaría de forma negativa.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Gracias por avisar, ahí agregué el código que vine haciendo hasta ahora, después de lo que puse no sé como seguir.

Comment: yo aparte de que creaste 14 variables para guardar datos (deberias crear un array de datos e ir verificando cada dato al ir ingresandolo) no entiendo cual es tu error.... ojala no te digan en el examen que podes ingresar 150 datos....

Comment: cuántos serían los productos defectuosos si todas las maquinas tuvieran la misma cantidad que la maquina que menos tiene, solo se refiere a calcular cual es el menor numero ingresado x14 que es el numero de máquinas. Si no te obliga a usar promp, sería mucho mas simple la validacion de un input type number. El numero de inputs tambien lo puedes generar con un for y el numero de inputs que desees.

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a Stackoverflow primero empezemos a colocar tu codigo mas bello cambia los defectuoso por un array y luego haces un for y dentro del for haces un push para agregar el valor, una vez esto puedes usar [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min) para ver el minimo y [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max) para ver el maximo

Comment: Si o si tenes que hacerlo con tantos promp. ¿No intentaste usar un bucle while y un array¿?

Comment: @CristianBudzicz no necesariamente tengo que hacer tantos promp, pero no quiero usar array porque es un tema que se supone todavía no enseñaron. También de momento me parece más fácil (para mi) usar esa cantidad de promp, pero cuando llego a la parte que mencioné antes no sé como seguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo. Te he puesto explicaciones y correcciones en los comentarios:

```js
    var maquinastotales = 14; // Declaro el número total de máquinas
    var defectuosos = []; // Creo un array vacío donde almacenaré los valores
    for (let index = 0; index < maquinastotales; index++) { // Un bucle for que se repetirá tantas veces como máquinas haya
        let valor = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', '')); //Recojo el valor
        while(isNaN(valor)){ //Si no es un número entrará aquí y lo repetirá hasta que sea un número válido
            valor = Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de productos defectuosos', ''));
        }
        defectuosos.push(valor); // Finalmente, meto el valor al array
    }
    var cant_defectuoso_total = 0;
    var promedio_productos;
    //Vamos a asumir que el primer valor es el menor y el mayor, simplemente para que la lógica de la comparación funcione
    var defectuoso_menor = defectuosos[0];
    var defectuoso_mayor = defectuosos[0];
    defectuosos.forEach(defectuoso => {// Recorro el array defectuosos almacenando cada valor en defectuoso, para ello utilizaré una función flecha
        if(defectuoso > defectuoso_mayor){// Si el valor de defectuosos de esta máquina es mayor que el que teniamos guardado
            defectuoso_mayor = defectuoso;// Lo actualizamos!
        }
        // Y lo mismo con el menor:
        if(defectuoso < defectuoso_menor){
            defectuoso_menor = defectuoso; // Si es menor, lo guardo en esta
        }
        // Finalmente sumo el valor al total haciendo un parseInt() para asegurarme que es un entero en la suma
        cant_defectuoso_total += parseInt(defectuoso);
    });

// // Este bucle hace exactamente lo mismo que lo de arriba, pero está escrito usando un bucle for normal:
// for(let i=0;i<defectuosos.length;i++){
//     let defectuoso = defectuosos[i]; /*Simplemente en cada vuelta del bucle (Iteración) 
//     cogemos el valor de defectuosos[i] y lo guardamos en defectuoso, a mano. En el bucle forEach como viste
//     el programa se encarga de hacer esa asignación por nosotros. A partir de aquí es lo mismo*/
//     if(defectuoso > defectuoso_mayor){// Si el valor de defectuosos de esta máquina es mayor que el que teniamos guardado
//         defectuoso_mayor = defectuoso;// Lo actualizamos!
//     }
//     // Y lo mismo con el menor:
//     if(defectuoso < defectuoso_menor){
//         defectuoso_menor = defectuoso; // Si es menor, lo guardo en esta
//     }
//     // Finalmente sumo el valor al total haciendo un parseInt() para asegurarme que es un entero en la suma
//     cant_defectuoso_total += parseInt(defectuoso);
// }

    //Este código se queda como estaba
    promedio_productos = cant_defectuoso_total / maquinastotales;
    document.write('Cantidad de productos defectuosos totales: '+cant_defectuoso_total+'<br />'); // Es buena práctica cerrar los elementos <br>
    document.write('Promedio de productos defectuosos por máquina: '+promedio_productos+'<br />');
    document.write('El menor número de defectuosos en una máquina ha sido: ' + defectuoso_menor + '<br />');
    document.write('El mayor número de defectuosos en una máquina ha sido: ' + defectuoso_mayor + '<br />');
    document.write('Si todas las máquinas tuviesen el mismo número de defectuosos' +
    'que la que menos tuvo, el total sería: ' + defectuoso_menor * maquinastotales + '<br />');
```

Te dejo por aquí también la documentación de las [`Funciones flecha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) de javascript,

Comment: `Math.max(defectuosos)`, `Math.min(defectuosos)`

Comment: De hecho, dado que es un array de enteros tendría que usar `Math.min.apply`, pero estaba intentando evitar usar funciones y enseñarle a hacer las cosas a mano, que para eso está aprendiendo. Ya tendrá tiempo de usar librerías cuando domine lo básico.

Comment: En realidad las funciondes de flecha no es lo mas llamativo, lo mas llamativo es usar un array y luego recorrerlo con forEach

Comment: Acaso no es [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) un método propio de los arrays? Acabo de terminar DAM y no he tocado mucho JavaScript, así que me interesaría saber por qué dices que es tan llamativo hacer eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, está muy bien explicado, mi duda es que no tengo claro es lo que dijeron antes, el forEach, ¿sirve para leer todos los datos dentro de la variable defectuoso?, también con index, que ese si que no sé de que funciona.

Comment: es para el usuario, lo hicistes de una forma diferente cambiastes 14 variables por un arreglo ademas usastes un metodo de JavaScript

Comment: @Josefina el del index, es un bucle for normal. Te cansarás de usarlos, el forEach es un poco diferente, simplemente quería que vieses dos formas rápidas de recorrer un array, aunque tal vez habría sido mejor utilizar otro bucle for normal. Pero no te preocupes, efectivamente el forEach sirve para leer todos los datos dentro del array `defectuosos`, uno a uno. El otro bucle lo que hace es repetir lo mismo 14 veces, desde que index vale 0, hasta que index valga lo mismo que `maquinastotales`, sumándole 1 cada vez (`index++`)

Comment: Te he añadido al ejemplo cómo quedaría recorrer el array con un bucle `for` además de con el `forEach` para que veas y compares. Cualquier cosa que no entiendas no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: @Benito-B Muchisimas gracias, se entendió todo perfecto.